# CDC or Oracle JavaME Embbed Client resources for MIPS

Tags: java-me, jvm, java, jvm-hotspot, cdc

I was asked to run a Java virtual machine on a Broadcom MIPS board and was very glad to find the OJEC cvm binary for MIPS from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javame/index.html). Unfortunately, it seems that the binary wasn't built for my board since it could not be executed properly.

```
/mnt/nfs/Oracle_JavaME_Embedded_Client/1.0/binaries/bin # ./cvm
-sh: ./cvm: not found
```

Can I ask anyone knows if I can get the OJEC source code somewhere to rebuild the client with our toolchain we're using for the board? If yes, is there a guide for building the client?

While searching google, I found a CDC source code from the "Phoneme" project and could build the cvm with our mips toolchain. It works fine! I could run its test and some hello world samples. However, looking at the Phoneme svn log, I realized that the project is not active recently, last change is about a year ago. Could someone tell the project's status and how it is different to the OJECT?

I'm also confused with openjdk's hotspot. Is it different to the OJEC? or are they both based on the CDC?

Here is the cpu info I got from my box's /proc/

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo 
system type : BCM7413B1 STB platform
processor : 0
cpu model : Broadcom BMIPS4380 V4.4 FPU V0.1
BogoMIPS : 404.48
wait instruction : yes
microsecond timers : yes
tlb_entries : 32
extra interrupt vector : yes
hardware watchpoint : no
ASEs implemented : mips16
shadow register sets : 1
core : 0
VCED exceptions : not available
VCEI exceptions : not available
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to chmod the file to `+x`

The binary is for mips32r2, your platform is mips32r1.

Answer (score 0):

Not much help, I know, but HotSpot is the OpenJDK (also the Oracle JVM) for its SE implementation - it isn't an ME implementation.

By the way, the command line you posted just looks like the cvm binary is missing in that directory.

Comment: Thanks! The cvm binary is there, that when I executed it. Maybe some missing libraries, I'll need ldd for that.